# How to use lodash to remove keys from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've been trying to transform some data using lodash without success. I am really new to javascript and lodash. How can I get the expected result?
I've used `mapValues` and `chain`, but I didn't achieve anything good.

```
const data = {
  "north": [
    {
      "2018-07-01": {
        "date": "2018-07-01",
        "name": "david",
        "age": 11
      },
      "2018-07-02": {
        "date": "2018-07-02",
        "name": "damo",
        "age": 16
      },
      "2018-07-03": {
        "date": "2018-07-03",
        "name": "dani",
        "age": 12
      }
    }
  ],
  "south": [
    {
      "2018-07-01": [
        {
          "fruit": "banana",
          "date": "2018-07-01",
          "name": "miller",
          "age": 11
        },
        {
          "fruit": "mango",
          "date": "2018-07-01",
          "name": "mano",
          "age": 11
        },
        {
          "fruit": "avocado",
          "date": "2018-07-01",
          "name": "karl",
          "age": 14
        }
      ],
      "2018-07-02": [
        {
          "fruit": "pineaplle",
          "date": "2018-07-02",
          "name": "gautier",
          "age": 12
        },
        {
          "fruit": "apple",
          "date": "2018-07-02",
          "name": "gauteng",
          "age": 9
        },
        {
          "fruit": "watermelon",
          "date": "2018-07-02",
          "name": "garzier",
          "age": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Below is the expected result. I am trying to remove the dates which are outside the objects and arrays.

```
const expectedData = {
  "north": [
    {
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "david",
      "age": 11
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "name": "damo",
      "age": 16
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-07-03",
      "name": "dani",
      "age": 12
    }
  ],
  "south": [
    {
      "fruit": "banana",
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "miller",
      "age": 11
    },
    {
      "fruit": "mango",
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "mano",
      "age": 11
    },
    {
      "fruit": "avocado",
      "date": "2018-07-01",
      "name": "karl",
      "age": 14
    },
    {
      "fruit": "pineaplle",
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "name": "gautier",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "fruit": "apple",
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "name": "gauteng",
      "age": 9
    },
    {
      "fruit": "watermelon",
      "date": "2018-07-02",
      "name": "garzier",
      "age": 12
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is using Lodash required? (It's not necessary at all)

Comment: @CertainPerformance using lodash is not required.

Comment: And have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Comment: I've made some attempts, but didn't get anywhere. I was able to transform the first object in the array with _.values(data[0]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need lodash for this. You can look at each key in your data and the just pull the values from each element of the array and concat it into a new array.

```js
const data = {"north": [{"2018-07-01": {"date": "2018-07-01","name": "david","age": 11},"2018-07-02": {"date": "2018-07-02","name": "damo","age": 16},"2018-07-03": {"date": "2018-07-03","name": "dani","age": 12}}],"south": [{"2018-07-01": [{"fruit": "banana","date": "2018-07-01","name": "miller","age": 11},{"fruit": "mango","date": "2018-07-01","name": "mano","age": 11},{"fruit": "avocado","date": "2018-07-01","name": "karl","age": 14}],"2018-07-02": [{"fruit": "pineaplle","date": "2018-07-02","name": "gautier","age": 12},{"fruit": "apple","date": "2018-07-02","name": "gauteng","age": 9},{"fruit": "watermelon","date": "2018-07-02","name": "garzier","age": 12}]}]};

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
    data[k] = data[k].reduce((a, c) => a.concat(...Object.values(c)), [])
})
console.log(data)
```

This starts with each key in your original object `north` and `south`. And for each one replaces the array with the accumulated values of each object in that array ignoring the keys.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could just do this

```
const expectedData = {
    north: Object.values(data.north[0]),
    south: Object.values(data.south[0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do any `lodash` quick operations, in pure JS way. But, since you tagged `lodash`
here is the version:

`_.mapValues(data, v => _.flatMapDeep(v, _.values))`

```js
var data = {
  "north": [
    {
      "2018-07-01": {
        "date": "2018-07-01",
        "name": "david",
        "age": 11
      },
      "2018-07-02": {
        "date": "2018-07-02",
        "name": "damo",
        "age": 16
      },
      "2018-07-03": {
        "date": "2018-07-03",
        "name": "dani",
        "age": 12
      }
    }
  ],
  "south": [
    {
      "2018-07-01": [
        {
          "fruit": "banana",
          "date": "2018-07-01",
          "name": "miller",
          "age": 11
        },
        {
          "fruit": "mango",
          "date": "2018-07-01",
          "name": "mano",
          "age": 11
        },
        {
          "fruit": "avocado",
          "date": "2018-07-01",
          "name": "karl",
          "age": 14
        }
      ],
      "2018-07-02": [
        {
          "fruit": "pineaplle",
          "date": "2018-07-02",
          "name": "gautier",
          "age": 12
        },
        {
          "fruit": "apple",
          "date": "2018-07-02",
          "name": "gauteng",
          "age": 9
        },
        {
          "fruit": "watermelon",
          "date": "2018-07-02",
          "name": "garzier",
          "age": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var expectedData = _.mapValues(data, v => _.flatMapDeep(v, _.values));

console.log(expectedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```